# Analog speedometer

Tags: android, graphics

Can somebody give me a tutorial on how to make an analog speedometer with Android? I have currently the speed (get by GPS), but I don't know how to do the graphic part.

Comment: Hi @user346665 did you get its solution?

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for something similar that I could convert into a game spinner. I found this tutorial for an analog thermometer. http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/

Answer (score 1):

Check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html Look for "ShapeDrawable". You are free to save the data in any format you like