# Positioning an image on top of an image with specific coordinates in Android

Tags: android, image, coordinates, css-position, android-framelayout

**End Goal:** Getting a speedometer style needle to move around a dial according to test results.

**Current Issue:** At the moment I have placed the needle on top of the speed dial as a sperate image using FrameLayout. I have been scouring the web for a way to position the needle with coordinates so I can have it exactly where I want it on the dial. I would post an image but I'm new to the forum and I'm not allowed!

So in short can I position an image over another image with exact coordinates (allowing for rotation etc)? Am I going the right way about solving my problem?

Comment: You should look into android canvas. You can do this using canvas and drawables.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Comment: I think this is the same question as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305281/analog-speedometer

Comment: Have a look at this rotary thermometer gauge: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/  Half way down the page is a download link to a zip of the source. You should be able to adapt it very easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [`AbsoluteLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html), which lets you use absolute positions, but **it is not recommended that you use it**.

Instead, you should create your own extension of a View, that draws your dial and needle. For more info on this, look at Maurycy's comment, which recommends [this part of the manual](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html).

Answer (score 0):

Calculate measurements and rotate image of indicator accordingly.